# Remove all unrewritten GET parameters from urls with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, clean-urls

I've noticed in Webmaster Tools a lot of urls have parameters added on, either on purpose or accidentally and it's looking like Google thinks these are separate pages.

All of my urls are rewritten and none contain any questions marks `?`, yet I see many urls like the following:

```
domain.com/profile/user-1?action=wahooo
domain.com/media/a-video?index=viewall
```

etc etc ...

**How can I remove all GET parameters from my urls using htaccess?**

I see the easiest solution would be some sort of rewrite to just remove everything after and including a question mark`?` but I'm struggling to find a way to do that with any parameter names and values?

Comment: Can you post your existing .htaccess code?

Answer (score 1):

You just need this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /([^\?\ ]*)\?
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
```

When there isn't a `QSA` flag, and the `?` is used in a rewrite rule's target, there will be a blank query string.

Comment: This seems to break the other rewrites?

Comment: @Silver89 what other rewrites? Don't know what to do or not do if I don't know anything about them.